# LiteDB exception when deployed to ARM device developed withUnity 2019.4.12f1

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arm, litedb

I'm trying to use LiteDB (net45, V5.0.9) in Unity 2019 targeting an ARM device. The [sample code](https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB#how-to-use-litedb) (provided in the docs) to perform CRUD operations works fine in the Unity editor but in the device I'm getting this exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Invalid BsonExpression when converted from Linq expression: x => x.Name - $.Name ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'LiteDB.BsonExpression' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: method
at System.Dynamic.Utils.ContractUtils.RequiresNotNull (System.Object value, System.String paramName) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call (System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression arg0, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression arg1) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at LiteDB.BsonExpressionParser.TryParsePath (LiteDB.Tokenizer tokenizer, LiteDB.ExpressionContext context, LiteDB.BsonDocument parameters, LiteDB.DocumentScope scope) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at LiteDB.BsonExpressionParser.ParseSingleExpression (LiteDB.Tokenizer tokenizer, LiteDB.ExpressionContext context, LiteDB.BsonDocument parameters, LiteDB.DocumentScope scope) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at LiteDB.BsonExpressionParser.ParseFullExpression (LiteDB.Tokenizer tokenizer, LiteDB.ExpressionContext context, LiteDB.BsonDocument parameters, LiteDB.DocumentScope scope) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at LiteDB.BsonExpression.Create (System.String expression, LiteDB.BsonDocument parameters) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at LiteDB.BsonExpression.Create (System.String expression) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at LiteDB.BsonExpression..cctor () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at LiteDB.LinqExpressionVisitor.Resolve (System.Boolean predicate) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at LiteDB.BsonMapper.GetExpression[T,K] (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression1[TDelegate] predicate) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at LiteDB.LiteCollection1[T].GetIndexExpression[K] (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression1[TDelegate] keySelector) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at LiteDB.LiteCollection1[T].EnsureIndex[K] (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression1[TDelegate] keySelector, System.Boolean unique) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
```

I did some googling and found a stack overflow question asking about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57570249/collection-find-collection-findall-all-throwing-exception-with-message), in which the one answer states that this could be due to missing dependencies. However, I am using the .NETFramework 4.5 DLL which according to the [NuGet page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LiteDB) does not have any dependencies.

Can someone help me out with this?

EDIT :

This is the sample code which I used:

```
// Create your POCO class
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string[] Phones { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

// Open database (or create if doesn't exist)
using(var db = new LiteDatabase(@"MyData.db"))
{
    // Get customer collection
    var col = db.GetCollection<Customer>("customers");

    // Create your new customer instance
    var customer = new Customer
    { 
        Name = "John Doe", 
        Phones = new string[] { "8000-0000", "9000-0000" }, 
        Age = 39,
        IsActive = true
    };

    // Create unique index in Name field
    col.EnsureIndex(x => x.Name, true);

    // Insert new customer document (Id will be auto-incremented)
    col.Insert(customer);

    // Update a document inside a collection
    customer.Name = "Joana Doe";

    col.Update(customer);

    // Use LINQ to query documents (with no index)
    var results = col.Find(x => x.Age > 20);
}
```

Could the issue be because of running this on IL2CPP backend?

Comment: Could you add the code that triggers the exception?

Comment: Added the sample code.

Comment: `x.Name` in `col.EnsureIndex(x => x.Name, true);` isnt returning null is it?

Comment: @Ben - it isn't but I did some digging and it seems like the issue is caused by IL2CPP's AOT compilation as described [here](https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB/issues/999). I guess there's no easy fix to use LiteDB as is.

Comment: @Vip12 I've used this https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3/ on Arm32 platforms with .netCore it might be of some use to you.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out what was causing the issue.

Unity was stripping assemblies as these were referenced through reflection. I specified the assemblies not to be stripped in the link.xml file as mentioned [here](https://gist.github.com/TigerHix/f270f2dc48222d17419bd46651926679). This solves the issue.